# Div не занимает 100% страницы

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте!

Словами не могу пояснить потому вот ссылка на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BvecU/1/)

Вопрос состоит в том, как сделать что бы фон был на всю страницу (div **d1**), потому как сейчас он только до конца **.d2**

Используйте скролинг

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MCubs/ - так?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V8jWW/ или так?

Comment: @soledar10 разницы не увидел. но не так важно. в body нельзя размещать. т.к. внутри тега будут другие div'ы

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BvecU/2/

Когда убираете попап - выставляйте для body overflow: auto

Comment: @dekameron иначе никак? верно?

Comment: @M11, "иначе" - можно еще что-то придумать, например [fancybox](http://fancybox.net), либо что-то [еще поискать](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/popup/)

Comment: @M11, иначе конечно же можно. Вообще есть масса способов, но самый простой с 'fixed'. Если он вам не подходит, то объясните почему.

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов если fixed то один модуль(внешний) работает не верно

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте для

```
.d1{position:fixed}
```

Comment: Нужно обязательно absolute